# What is the jdbc driver "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" for?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, drivers

After taking over a coworker's project I noticed he was using "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" as the jdbc driver for MySQL 5 instead of the more common one "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".  They both are contained in the driver I found on Maven central that appears to be the standard distribution of the driver.

When I look up gjt.org I found some old site that talks about "Mark's mysql driver".

http://gjt.org/

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The MySQL JDBC driver was initially developed by a hobbyist. It's later donated to MySQL where they renamed the package/classname. The old classname is kept for backwards compatibility reasons, but if you can, you should update it to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` as soon as possible.