# how to change driver class in HIbernate Configuration file (cfg.xml)

Tags: java, hibernate, classnotfoundexception, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am trying to create a  my first hibernate application in these application by using hibernate tool i am trying to create cfg.xml file but in these file Driver class is "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" itis coming  default for MYSQL 5 but while doing hibernate code generation configuration it's throwing the exception that driver ClassNotFound exception

Comment: Can you post your config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post.

[What is the jdbc driver "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808160/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-for)

You need to download correct [mysql connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and put it on your classpath as the one you are using (org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver) is very old

And change your hibernate configuration to use it.

Comment: I am now trying to use these driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver but now i got error as in hibernate code generation configuration their is some problem in path of output directory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the jar file containing the driver is in your classpath when you run the hibernate tool.

Comment: my jar file is present in Referenced Library