# error in connecting to a local database (java)

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection, local

I am using xampp Control Panel v3.1.0 , I have imported a database to myphpadmin   and i am trying to connect to my local database sam but i am not sure why i keep getting the following errors:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at system.DBConnector.connect(DBConnector.java:28)


public class DBConnector {
        public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        public static final String DATABASE = "sam";
        public static final String DRIVER = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
        public static final String USERNAME = "";
        public static final String PASSWORD = "";
        private static Connection connection = null;
        private static Statement statement = null;
        private static PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        private static ResultSet resultSet = null;

        /** Open database connection to a specified database */
        protected void connect() {
            try {
                Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL+DATABASE,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you add location (probably JAR) of `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` to classpath?

Comment: Also interesting fact [what-is-the-jdbc-driver-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808160/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-for).

Comment: I am not really sure how to do this can you show me please

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: We don't know what platform you're working on. Here's some generic information: https://www.google.com/search?q=adding+a+jar+to+a+classpath

Comment: i am working on windows

Comment: yes i am using eclipse