# Registered driver with driverClassName=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver was not found

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm developing a project and using a spring.
It works correctly, but when I added a database to it, I got some exceptions.

```
WARN com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : root - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]......
```

dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.detectlanguage</groupId>
        <artifactId>detectlanguage</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

application.property:

```
#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mSecond
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.name=name
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

The address of the database is correct and working - 100%

Can someone show another method, more correct for database initialization in the spring?

Comment: That is just a warning and is not the cause of your problem. See here about the warning: [What is the jdbc driver “org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver” for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5808160/5221149) It's an old obsolete name. Stop using it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Do not use this since it has been DEPRECATED!

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Use this instead

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
```

Comment: changing from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver worked for me

Comment: This correct for me when I have host in Java 12 (Oracle), the previous one is OK at Java 8. Java 12: correct driver name `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: same here .. its also worked for me

Answer (score 4):

If you change your properties file with the following lines it should work:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
```

This driver class is fine for mysql and you need to use `spring.datasource.username=` instead of `spring.datasource.name=`

I hope this helps you

Comment: you saved one year of my life)