# INSERT IN SQL TABLE using java does not work

Tags: java, mysql

I wanted to insert the data into my sql database that I manage locally using myadmiphp. I have written this code but it gives me the exception why?

```
public void  insertInto(int m1, int m2,int m3,int m4,int m5,int m6,int m7,int m8,int m9,int m10,int m11,int m12,int m13,double deviazione, String paziente){
     try
     {
         // create a mysql database connection
         String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
         String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_bhkreportpatient";
         Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, 
          "bhkreportpatient", "");

         // create a sql date object so we can use it in our INSERT statement
             Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              java.sql.Date data = new 
            java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());

         // the mysql insert statement
         String query = " insert into bhk (Metrica1, Metrica2, Metrica3, Metrica4, Metrica5,Metrica6,Metrica7,Metrica8,Metrica9,Metrica10,Metrica11,Metrica12,Metrica13,Data,Deviazione_standard,Paziente)"
                 + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

         // create the mysql insert preparedstatement
         PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
         preparedStmt.setInt (1, m1);
         preparedStmt.setInt (2, m2);
         preparedStmt.setInt (3, m3);
         preparedStmt.setInt (4, m4);
         preparedStmt.setInt (5, m5);
         preparedStmt.setInt (6, m6);
         preparedStmt.setInt (7, m7);
         preparedStmt.setInt (8, m8);
         preparedStmt.setInt (9, m9);
         preparedStmt.setInt (10,m10);
         preparedStmt.setInt (11,m11);
         preparedStmt.setInt (12,m12);
         preparedStmt.setInt (13, m13);
         preparedStmt.setDate   (14,data);
         preparedStmt.setDouble(15, deviazione);

         preparedStmt.setString(16, paziente.toUpperCase());


         // execute the preparedstatement
         preparedStmt.execute();

         conn.close();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         System.err.println("Got an exception!");
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
     }
```

call of method:

```
insertInto(first, second, third, forth, fifth, sixth, seventh,eighth, ninth, tenth, eleventh, twelveth, thirteenth,finalScore,"BVNVCN97250l0");
```

Exception is:

```
Got an exception!
org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.
```

What is `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver`?

```
 error is:
           java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at Metrics.ParametersFrame$1.insertInto(ParametersFrame.java:410)
    at Metrics.ParametersFrame$1.actionPerformed(ParametersFrame.java:378)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Why don't you print the whole stacktrace and see what the problem is?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: or at **very least**, print the exception, not only its message `System.err.println(e);` - normally `printStackTrace()` is better, not only prints the Exception but also indicates where it happened.

Comment: Waiting for the stack trace but I assume you missed the corresponding jar on your classpath.

Comment: Have a look at this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808160/what-is-the-jdbc-driver-org-gjt-mm-mysql-driver-for

Answer (score 1):

Change your jdbc driver name to

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```